# SQL Server Connection Read Timeout

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, etl, talend, data-integration

I am trying to load from a SQL Server 2012 to Azure SQL Server using Talend. Job will read all the data from the source DB and load into destination. All the jobs are doing truncate and load. Lot of tables have records more than 7 millions. 5 tables have nearly 25 million records. I have one master job which will trigger all the jobs in parallel. I am facing a ***com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection timed out (Read failed)*** issue.

When anyone of the job/table throws this error, all the jobs that are running parallelly also throws the same error. What is the reason for this issue and how to fix it?

Thanks,

Comment: Probably something else on the server slowing things down

Comment: Main problem is when any of the job throws Read Time out error, all the other jobs running in parallel fails immediately due to this error. How to prevent this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server process Task state Suspended and Read Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69665733/sql-server-process-task-state-suspended-and-read-timeout) You posted the same thing twice

Comment: No. I am trying to find whether the issue is in Talend or SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

"When you connect to a SQL Server 2012 instance running on Windows Server 2012, you get time-out error messages."

It's possible that the test server didn't get the same Windows updates as the production server. That might explain why production code and configuration are identical.

This is the [Original Post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/afb47f41-5196-4e30-8213-d72cddb79641/sqlexception-read-timed-out-clientconnectionidf9c1a8c4326a4945a166e0c906bfe4e5?forum=sqlgetstarted), this issue might be caused by something unrelated to Java JDBC, such as SSMS or applications that do not use JDBC.

> 1. Verify that you can ping the SQL Server-installed server.
> 2. Verify that the SQL Server instance is up and operating.
> 3. Double-check that the connection codes you used are valid.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question. I am not getting timeout all the time. When I am running queries for big tables(25 millions records), I am getting read timeout

Comment: Thank you for letting me know- may I know which kind of queries you have been running - So will edit my answer with respect to that.

Comment: SELECT * FROM TABLENAME. No other filter condition/Group By