# SQL Server process Task state Suspended and Read Timeout

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, etl, talend, timeoutexception

I am running parallelly multiple queries in a SQL Server. All of them is simple select statement without any filter/group by condition. Queries are running through Talend ETL tool. When I check the Activity Monitor, lot of processes are in Suspended state. And I am facing **Read Timeout**, when one query/job gets this error, all the other queries/jobs fails due to this.
My questions is

1. Is there way to reduce the number of processes in Suspended State at a time?
2. How to avoid the Read Timeout error and how to make other queries executing in parallel run without any issue?
3. Fetching data takes more than an hour for some tables. How to reduce this time?

Thanks

Comment: First thing: stop running them in parallel. If they are IO-bound (and they usually are) then you are not speeding them up by running them in parallel. For better help we need to see queries, tables, indexes, and query plans (you can share those via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: There are simple select queries without any filter/group by condition and it fetches all the records from the table.

Comment: If they are simple and run quickly why do you need to run them in parallel? Clearly the server is getting overloaded and suspending some queries in favor of others. Have you checked there is nothing else running at the same time, such as a backup job or maintenance job?

Comment: Just to clarify, it is simple select query but it is not running quickly. I am reading millions of records. Reason I am running in parallel is to reduce the run time. 90% of the jobs are running in parallel, but it still took 8 to 9 hrs to complete. I want to reduce this time.